# what does operator precedence and associativity means in c#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know what precedence and associativity means.
What is the order of the precedence?
I have an expression and i dont understand how the answer is 8?

```
int a=5;
int c=2;
int b=a++ * (c+10)/ (a+1);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You would have gotten an instant answer if you would have typed that into your favourite search engine rather than ask here.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to apply the operators in the order you see them to understand this.

```
int b=a++ * (c+10)/ (a+1);
```

First you have `a++`. This means that you use the actual value of `a`, and then increase it by 1. So there you would replace `a` by 5, and then replace the current stored value of `a` by 1, giving 6. For the rest, as there is nothing special, you just replace the values by the stored values, knowing now that `a` is equal to 6.

```
    b = 5 * (2+10) / (6+1)
=>  b = 5 * 12 / 7
=>  b = 8 (as b is an integer, the real value would be ~8.57 for a float value)
```